# Fiscal week are not coming in order

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I am writing a query in which i want to order it by FiscalPeriod [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdZl2.png) but i am not getting the expected result the fiscal weeks are coming in random sequence. my order by clause looks like

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 4, 2) AS INT), CONVERT(DATETIME, FiscalPeriod, 106)
```

data type in FiscalPeriod is nvarchar, and format is like '07-Apr-02' where 07 is fiscal month and 02 week number in current month.

I am expecting fiscal week should be in sequence.

Comment: Add `CAST(SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 4, 2) AS INT), CONVERT(DATETIME, FiscalPeriod, 106)` to your SELECT list, and you'll perhaps see whats going on.

Comment: hi jarlh, i did but still getting same error

Comment: Of course, but when you take a look at your new columns, do you understand the ORDER BY problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 1,2) + SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 8,2) as INT)
```

If FiscalPeriod is `'07-Apr-02'` then `SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 1,2)` gives us `'07'` and SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 8,2) gives is `'02'`. Concatenate them to to give `'0702'` and then `CAST` this to an `INT` to give `702`

Ifg you want to use this in SSRS to order columns etc, then you probably don't need to use `ORDER BY` in your dataset query, instead you can just add a new column that contains this value and then order the column group by this value in SSRS.

So instead of

```
SELECT ClusterName, EmployeeName, SomeOtherColume 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 1,2) + SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 8,2) as INT)
```

Just do this instead

```
SELECT ClusterName, EmployeeName, SomeOtherColume 
   CAST(SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 1,2) + SUBSTRING(FiscalPeriod, 8,2) as INT) as FPSort
FROM myTable
```

In the matrix column group, use `FPSort` as the sort column.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you very much for help. This one worked for me, but if i try to filter it in SSRS using USERID, then i am getting the same problem.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered the question you posted, please mark it an accepted (the check mark to the left, under the vote up/down buttons). If you still have other problems, then you need to ask a new question.

Comment: I've added a bit more to the answer that might help you to implement this in SSRS